# Test not compiling - operator overrides in C#

Tags: c#, overriding, operator-keyword, assert

I'm using a struct with 2 properties, and I'm overriding some operators in order to compare, add and subtract them on the basis of their 'amount'.

```
public struct CurrencyAmount
{
    private decimal amount;
    private string currency;

    public CurrencyAmount(decimal amount, string currency)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public static decimal operator +(CurrencyAmount amount1, CurrencyAmount amount2)
    {
        if (amount1.currency != amount2.currency) throw new ArgumentException();
        return amount1.amount + amount2.amount;
    }
    public static decimal operator -(CurrencyAmount amount1, CurrencyAmount amount2)
    {
        if (amount1.currency != amount2.currency) throw new ArgumentException();
        return amount1.amount - amount2.amount;
    }
```

My problem is that this test doesn't compile:

```
    [Property]
public void Addition_with_same_currency(decimal value1, decimal value2)
{
    var amount1 = new CurrencyAmount(value1, "HD");
    var amount2 = new CurrencyAmount(value2, "HD");
    var expected = new CurrencyAmount(value1 + value2, "HD");

    Assert.Equal(expected, amount1 + amount2);
}
```

I get a CS1503 error : Argument 1: cannot convert from 'CurrencyAmount' to 'string' and Argument 2: cannot convert from 'decimal' to 'string', from the 'expected' and 'amount1 + amount2' parameters respectively.

but this test compiles and passes:

```
    [Property]
public void Addition_is_commutative(decimal value1, decimal value2)
{
    var amount1 = new CurrencyAmount(value1, "HD");
    var amount2 = new CurrencyAmount(value2, "HD");

    Assert.Equal(amount1 + amount2, amount2 + amount1);
}
```

So the addition operator appears to be overridden properly. What am I missing here?

Comment: Technical point: you haven't *overridden* operators (and you can't). You've *overloaded* them. (Will look at the rest when I get a chance...)

Comment: Separately - it would also help if you'd reduce this to a minimal example. I don't think the `==`, `!=`, `<` or `>` operators are being used, so you can remove them from the example. I also think your `Equals` method doesn't do what you'd expect it to (and may well throw a StackOverflow exception).

Comment: `expected` is a `CurrencyAmount` where as `amount1 + amount2` is a `decimal`, because the overloaded `operator +` returns a `decimal`. You should probably return a `CurrencyAmount` with `return new CurrencyAmount(amount1.amount + amount2.amount, amount1.currency);`

Comment: The - operator does the wrong calculation -=

Comment: I've edited down the code for brevity

Comment: OK, thanks for all your comments. I see the problem with returning the wrong type, although i'm not sure how the other tests passed on that case. The problem is with my Equals method. it now looks like this:

`public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is CurrencyAmount)) return false;
        return Equals((CurrencyAmount)obj);
    }
    public bool Equals(CurrencyAmount other)
    {
        if (other.amount != amount) return false;
        return other.currency == currency;
    }`
sorry, I tried formatting the code...

Answer (score -1):

`amount1 + amount2` returns a `decimal` and then you are basically trying to equate a `CurrencyAmount` with a `decimal`.

I would suggest making the `+` operator return a new `CurrencyAmount`:

```
public static CurrencyAmount operator +(CurrencyAmount amount1, 
    CurrencyAmount amount2)
{
    if (amount1.currency != amount2.currency) throw new ArgumentException();
    return new CurrencyAmount(amount1.amount + amount2.amount, amount1.currency);
}
```

Another option would be to create an `==` operator that takes a decimal, though you would lose the currency type check:

```
public static bool operator ==(CurrencyAmount amount1, decimal amount2)
{
    return (amount1.amount == amount2);
}

public static bool operator !=(CurrencyAmount amount1, decimal amount2)
{
    return (amount1.amount != amount2);
}
```

And now you could do:

```
Assert.True(expected == (amount1 + amount2));
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason it is failing to compile is because `Assert.AreEqual` requires two objects of the same type. You are passing it a `CurrencyAmount` and a `decimal`, which are different types.

While DavidG's answer is correct, there is a simpler solution, although it requires you to change the access modifier of `CurrencyAmount.amount`. What is the point of a struct with all private members anyway?

My best guess from your code is that you want something like this:

```
   public struct CurrencyAmount
    {
        public decimal Amount { get; }
        public string Currency { get; }

        public CurrencyAmount(decimal amount, string currency)
        {
            Amount = amount;
            Currency = currency;
        }

        public static decimal operator +(CurrencyAmount amount1, CurrencyAmount amount2)
        {
            if (amount1.Currency != amount2.Currency) throw new ArgumentException();
            return amount1.Amount + amount2.Amount;
        }
        public static decimal operator -(CurrencyAmount amount1, CurrencyAmount amount2)
        {
            if (amount1.Currency != amount2.Currency) throw new ArgumentException();
            return amount1.Amount - amount2.Amount;
        }
    }

    [Property]
    public void Addition_with_same_currency(decimal value1, decimal value2)
    {
        var amount1 = new CurrencyAmount(value1, "HD");
        var amount2 = new CurrencyAmount(value2, "HD");
        var expected = new CurrencyAmount(value1 + value2, "HD");

        Assert.Equal(expected.Amount, amount1 + amount2);
    }
```

Also, I think you made a typo by defining the `-` operator as `-=`.